# tomcat 9 service opens handle(?) on tomcat 9 command line instance

Tags: tomcat

myapp on tomcat 9 service is here:
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\myapp

myapp on tomcat 9 on command line is here:
C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.8\webapps\myapp

both run fine separatly (on separate ports, http connector, shutdown, ajp, etc...).  but when service is running, and i try to rebuild/deploy the command line instance somehow it seems that the service has a file handle open on the command line files system and myapp can not be removed.

this 2 instance configuration worked fine with the same code running on tomcat 6 (jdk 7).  now is tomcat 9 on jdk 10...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind.  found this in my logback.xml

```
<property name="DEV_HOME" value="C:/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/webapps/ews/WEB-INF/logs" />
```